# Javascript Email validation + text adding miss behaving

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email, text

I am trying to make a form validation in 2 steps. One client side, one server side. I managed to get some parts of the client check working. I am experiencing peculiar bugs... The code:

```
//global vars
 var form, cegnev, cegnevInfo, cegcim, cegcimInfo, cegemail, cegemailInfo, cegkapcs, cegkapcsInfo, cegbeosz, cegbeoszInfo;
form = $("#jelentkezes");  
cegnev = $("#ceg_nev");  
cegnevInfo = $("#ceg_nevInfo");
cegcim = $("#ceg_cim");  
cegcimInfo = $("#ceg_cimInfo");   
cegemail = $("#ceg_cim");  
cegemailInfo = $("#ceg_emailInfo");
cegkapcs = $("#ceg_kapcs");  
cegkapcsInfo = $("#ceg_kapcsInfo");
cegbeosz = $("#ceg_beosz");
cegbeoszInfo = $("#ceg_beszInfo");
(function () {
"use strict";
// this function is strict...
$(document).ready(function () {
    function validateCegemail() {
        //testing regular expression
        var a = $("#ceg_email").val(), filter = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        //if it's valid email
        if (filter.test(a)) {
            cegemail.removeClass("elizelte");
            cegemailInfo.removeClass("elizelte");
            cegemailInfo.text("Jó!");
            cegemail.addClass("lotto");
            cegemailInfo.addClass("lotto");
            return true;
        } else {
         //if it's NOT valid
            cegemail.removeClass("lotto");
            cegemailInfo.removeClass("lotto");
            cegemail.addClass("elizelte");
            cegemailInfo.text("E-mail formátuma nem megfelelő! pl: valaki@vhalahol.hu");
            cegemailInfo.addClass("elizelte");
            return false;
        }
    }
    function validateCegnev() {  
        //if it's NOT valid
        if (cegnev.val().length < 7) {
            cegnev.removeClass("lotto");
            cegnevInfo.removeClass("lotto");
            cegnev.addClass("elizelte");  
            cegnevInfo.text("Cég névnek több mint 7 betűből kell állnia!");  
            cegnevInfo.addClass("elizelte");  
            return true;
        } else {
    //if it's valid     
            cegnev.removeClass("elizelte");   
            cegnevInfo.removeClass("elizelte");
            cegnevInfo.text("Jó!"); 
            cegnev.addClass("lotto");
            cegnevInfo.addClass("lotto"); 
            return false;  
        }  
    }
    function validateCegbeosz() {  
        //if it's NOT valid
        if (cegbeosz.val().length < 4) {
            cegbeosz.removeClass("lotto");
            cegbeoszInfo.removeClass("lotto");
            cegbeosz.addClass("elizelte");  
            cegbeoszInfo.text("Beosztás minimum 4 betűből kell, hogy álljon!");  
            cegbeoszInfo.addClass("elizelte");  
            return true;
        } else {
    //if it's valid         
            cegbeosz.removeClass("elizelte");   
            cegbeoszInfo.removeClass("elizelte");
            cegbeoszInfo.text("Jó!"); 
            cegbeosz.addClass("lotto");
            cegbeoszInfo.addClass("lotto"); 
            return false;  
        }  
    }
    function validateCegkapcs() {
        //if it's valid
        var a = $("#ceg_kapcs").val(), filter = /^(\b[a-zA-Z.-]+\b.*){2,4}$/;
        if (filter.test(a)) {
            cegkapcs.removeClass("elizelte");
            cegkapcsInfo.removeClass("elizelte");
            cegkapcsInfo.text("Jó!");
            cegkapcs.addClass("lotto");
            cegkapcsInfo.addClass("lotto");
            return true;
        } else {
        //Ha if it's NOT valid
            cegkapcs.removeClass("lotto");
            cegkapcsInfo.removeClass("lotto");
            cegkapcs.addClass("elizelte");
            cegkapcsInfo.text("Kis és nagybetű, szóköz és kőtőjel csak a megengedett!");
            cegkapcsInfo.addClass("elizelte");
            return false;
        }
    }
//On blur  
    cegnev.blur(validateCegnev);  
    cegemail.blur(validateCegemail);
    cegkapcs.blur(validateCegkapcs);  
    cegbeosz.blur(validateCegbeosz);
//On key press  
    cegnev.keyup(validateCegnev);
    cegemail.keyup(validateCegemail);       
    cegkapcs.keyup(validateCegkapcs);
    cegbeosz.keyup(validateCegbeosz);
```

I don't know whats appropriate or not posting the whole code, or just the parts I have a genuine problem with, excuse me for not knowing that. My problem is that 2 validations work flawlessly. One that does "cegnev" and one that does "cegkapcs". The other two screw themselfs up, but differently. The cegemail does NOT work at ALL. cegbeosz does work to an extent but does NOT change the text.

The "testing" website can be checked at www.tudatoskommunikacio.hu/gergo if u want to check out the html part of it. I am quite new to javascript, and I do beleive that is causing the erros. I tried to narrow down my mistakes by using Jlint, but beside a few problems, that I read across the web I can live with, nothing stands out as a mayor flaw. Thanks for the help, I am quite desperate here...

Answer (score 0):

It's just a copy-paste error by the look of it. At the top of your code:

```
cegcim = $("#ceg_cim");  
cegcimInfo = $("#ceg_cimInfo");   
cegemail = $("#ceg_cim");  
cegemailInfo = $("#ceg_emailInfo");
```

You are selecting the **ceg_sim** id for the **cegemail** variable

Your other issue is also just a trivial spelling mistake:

```
cegbeosz = $("#ceg_beosz");
cegbeoszInfo = $("#ceg_beszInfo");
```

You're missing an "o".

I strongly recommend using a javascript debugger in future to catch these trivial mistakes.